# pushing to new UIViewController through custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios5, storyboard

I am using this function but it is not working. I'm using StoryBoard and xcode 4.3.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

     pushnavViewController *detailViewController = [[pushnavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"pushnavViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.pushh.text = [listt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working, describe the expected outcome, and what you're getting, and how they're different.

Comment: i am expecting to push to new viewcontroller when i select certain row

Comment: Remove this row `detailViewController.pushh.text = [listt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` and try again.

Comment: but it is not pushing when i select the row

Comment: @CemalEker i tried but it is not working

Comment: Did you set this object as delegate of this table view controller. You should add a line like `[self.tableview setDelegate:self];` in init.

Comment: the table view is working fine , but the problem it is not pushing

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your didSelectRow... function, is it being reached? Also, are you sure self.navigationController is not nil (i.e. the view controller you are pushing from is in a navigation controller's stack)?

Comment: yeah, it is reaching the function but not pushing the cell to new viewcontroller
@happypig

Comment: And the pushing view controller is definitely in a navigation controller stack?

Comment: @happypig i do not know what are you saying about stack thing !

Comment: Is your pushing view controller 'inside' a navigation controller?

Comment: i do not know , how to make it ? 
or how to know if i am  doing this or no ? thanks in advance ..

Comment: Do you either have some code that says:`self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];`. Or is the view controller inside a navigation controller in Interface Builder or in your storyboard?

Comment: in .m ? no i do not have

Comment: How about in IB or storyboard?

Comment: i tried to make navigation view controller from storyboard and make relationship to tableview then push from cell to the new viewcontroller but also not working ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer :

when you are using storyboard you have to use

```
pushnavViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pushnavViewController"];
```

NOT

```
     pushnavViewController *detailViewController = [[pushnavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"pushnavViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Also, do not forget to set the Identifier from storyborad .

Comment: Glad you found the answer. I'm still a bit behind when it comes to using the storyboard...

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd take this out of the comments and have a stab at a solution. Sorry it's not a direct solution, but more of a suggestion...

Maybe the best thing to do is (if you're using Xcode 4.x) to create a new project selecting the 'Master-Detail Application' template. Look in the AppDelegate class and see how the MasterViewController is added as the root view controller of the UINavigationController there. See how this works and try to apply the same to your situation.

Also, look at the class reference for the UINavigationController.

Comment: thanks it work, but it is not go back and giving me this error 

2012-06-29 01:43:49.229 mywordpressblog[8446:f803] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-06-29 01:43:49.229 mywordpressblog[8446:f803] here
2012-06-29 01:43:49.582 mywordpressblog[8446:f803] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-06-29 01:43:49.584 mywordpressblog[8446:f803] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <pushnavViewController: 0x6845bf0>.

Comment: 2012-06-29 01:44:00.450 mywordpressblog[8446:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/alialzahrani/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/FBA2F88E-CAE8-482C-9883-C96B2B9186CB/mywordpressblog.app> (loaded)' with name 'pushnavViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13e8022 0x1579cd6 0x1390a48 0x13909b9 0x253638 0xf91fc 0xf9779 0xf999b 0xf9d11 0x10bd1e 0x10c85f 0x10db4b 0x10de26 0x10cf90 0x10ee37 0x991ee 0x99179 0x9bc37 0x9be7c 0x5a3c0 0x5a5e6 0x40dc4 0x34634

Comment: 0x12d2ef5 0x13bc195 0x1320ff2 0x131f8da 0x131ed84 0x131ec9b 0x12d17d8 0x12d188a 0x32626 0x21dd 0x2145)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Comment: Assuming your nib file is in the right place and you have used the correct name, try doing Product > Clean, then re-running.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I can add more to this new development with your issue. If you ensure that yours is set up in the same way as the template, then you shouldn't have an issue...

Answer (score 0):

1- Create story board Identifier: pushnavViewController
   Click on ViewController, choose tab identity inspector ==> Storyboard ID: pushnavViewController

2- Initiate UIViewController using Storyboard Identifier

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = self.storyboard;
    UIViewController *mainViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pushnavViewController"];
```

3- Push to another ViewController
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainViewController animated:YES];

Here is the code:

```
-(void) openABCPage
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = self.storyboard;
    UIViewController *mainViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pushnavViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainViewController animated:YES];

}
```